# Newest Product Widget Not Showing Correct Products

Tags: ce-1.9.2.0, widget, new-products

I have a recent problem with the new product widget not actually displaying the newest products. It is set to 'all products-recently added products' but has just been showing the same 5 products for the last 2 months, regardless of the products that have just been added...

Does anyone have any ideas on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 4):

Date also plays an important role. While inserting the product details.

You give recent date and you paste this code in the home page By going to cms and manage pages of Magento admin panel.

I am new to magento and i tried it. It worked for me.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```