# Products won't show up on my website! (search, catalog, categories)

Tags: catalog, products, search, advanced-search

Since today, my products have stopped displaying on the website! I don't remember making any changes to `.xml`, `.phtml` files. I have already gone through **checking the stock, inventory, enabled, visibility, cache, index and so on.** But they still won't show up.

I can still navigate to the products with the `url-key`. Also, noteworthy is that when I search for the products using **search** or **advanced search,** it comes up with results, but it just won't display it. Please see the screenshots below to understand the issue.

**EDIT: Also, both search and advanced search seem to break the page i.e  the footer doesn't show up too.**

## Case 1

However, when searching for a "hot huez" (name of a product), which matches the title of the product, it returns with what I believe to be **the results** without the actual product?

[image]

## Case 2 (advanced search)

The advanced search even acknowledges that there is a product matching the criteria, but still doesn't display it. I'm at my wit's end, does anyone have any idea, what I might be missing?

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try to reindex from the commandline and check for any errors

Comment: @SanderMangel How would I go on to do that?

Comment: Log in via SSH onto your server and from the directory Magento is in execute `php shell/indexer.php reindexall`

Comment: Otherwise reindex from backend but make sure they all finish and are updated (check date) and no errors are found in the Magento logging

Comment: can u try this .and lets see http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/78869/28660

Comment: @SudhirBelagali Thanks for the effort there, but it doesn't work. It breaks the rest of the code (html footer). I don't know what could be causing this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after spending a few hours, I have finally found out the issue. I hope that this will help others facing the same issue and have no clue how to resolve it.

So what is the issue causing search to malfunction an break the HTML Page?

It's...

**System > Configuration > Catalog > Use Flat Catalog Product**

So, if you have "innocently" changed this setting to "Yes", this is going to break your search! So make sure this is set to "No" (like it is by default) and hopefully things should return to the normal course!

*Phew!*

Comment: I use flat catalog and have not had any problems like this. You should try the manual reindex via command line `/usr/local/php55/bin/php-cli -f shell/indexer.php reindexall` after saving this configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this many times.

If you're using Solr to drive your category and search and Solr goes down - or the index has become corrupt - Then all of your search results and category pages will return 0 results.

This is easily remedied in most cases by restarting Solr and reindexing the Catalog Search and related Flat catalog indexes.

Comment: I have no idea what `Solr` is and I have never used it. Sorry!

Comment: Has your systems integrator incorporated it?

Comment: No. I'm quite positive that we haven't incorporated Solr.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the following items in the admin interface:

1. In General -> Status must be set to **Enabled**, Visibility must be set to **Catalog, Search**
2. In Inventory -> Quantity must be more than 0 and Stock Availability must be set to **In Stock**

Obviously, all the mandatory fields must be compiled and I suggest you specify some categories for the product.

Comment: As the question suggests, I have already checked these things beforehand. It doesn't make a difference.