# Home page doesn't changes

Tags: magento-1.9.2.0

[image: **enter image description here**]
I am newbie. I have created catalogs and added products but nothing is showing on the home page.. 1. it is active. 2.navigation menu yes 3. static block

Comment: Run all your indexes in Index Management

Comment: This link helps u to display atleast products http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/78869/28660